# trouble with 2nd AP/DHCP Server

Tags: networking, wifi

I've got my FIOS router currently proving wifi, I bought a raspberry pi 2 to add a second AP with DHCP in a different area in the house to fill a strength void.  (I don't mind having the fios router server 192.168.1.1-150 and the raspberry server 192.168.1.151-250 - or a separate range).

I can connect to the wireless part of it but it won't ping out anywhere. I've got the following in my udhcpd.conf file

```
start           192.168.42.1    #default: 192.168.0.20
end             192.168.42.200  #default: 192.168.0.254
interface       wlan0           #default: eth0
remaining     yes
opt     dns     8.8.8.8 8.8.2.2
option  subnet  255.255.255.0
option  broadcast       192.168.42.255
opt     router  192.168.42.1
option  lease   864000          # 10 days of seconds
```

This is my /etc/network/interfaces file.
    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback

```
iface eth0 inet manual

iface wlan0 inet static
  address 192.168.42.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.1.15
up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat
```

And lastly this is my iptables.ipv4

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Sat Nov 21 01:17:14 2015
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [164:17939]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [100:9664]
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Nov 21 01:17:14 2015
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Sat Nov 21 01:17:14 2015
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [26:2921]
:INPUT ACCEPT [2:1793]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [6:500]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Nov 21 01:17:14 2015
```

Any ideas?